# Subspace of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ that deformation retracts to any point in $[0,1] \times \{0\}$, but not any other point.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, solution-verification, retraction

This is an exercise that I'm doing, and I would like some comment on my solution.

[image]

This is the picture I have in my head, where $(p,0)$ is the point $X$ deformation retracts to, and $(x_1,x_2)$ another point of $X$.

[image]

My idea of the homotopy $H: X \times I \to X$ that serves as the deformation retraction is the part colored in red, i.e. it consists of two paths that first send $(x_1, x_2)$ to $(x_1,0)$, then $(x_1,0)$ to $(p,0)$. Is this acceptable?

If yes, why wouldn't it work with any other point not in $[0,1] \times \{0\}$? I'd like to have some clues for this part as well.

---

**Edit:** after reading the answer below, I rechecked my materials and realized that the definition of DR that we use is actually called strong DR elsewhere. That'd got me confused a bit since I had been reading different sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must distinguish between a *deformation retract* and a *strong deformation retract*. A retraction $r : Z \to A$ to a subset $ A \subset Z$ is a *deformation retraction* if there exists a homotopy $H : Z \times [0,1] \to R$ such that $H(z,0) = z$ and $H(z,1) = r(z)$. If exists a homotopy such that in addition $H(a,t) = a$ for all $a \in A, t \in [0,1]$, then $r$ is called a *strong deformation retraction*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract.

A strong deformation retraction to a point $p_0 \in Y  = [0,1] \times \{0\}$ can be composed by the obvious strong deformation retraction of $X$ to $Y$ and the obvious strong deformation retraction of $Y$ to $p_0$.

Why doesn't this work for $p_0 \in U =  X \setminus Y$? Note that $U$ is open in $X$ and has infinitely many path components $U_r = \{r\} \times (0,1-r]$, $r \in [0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, any open subset of $X$ intersects infinitely many of the $U_r$.

Now assume we have a strong deformation retraction $r : X \to \{p_0\}$. There is a homotopy $H : X \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $H(x,0) = x$, $H(x,1) = p_0$ and $H(p_0,t) = p_0$. Since $U$  is an open neigborhood of $p_0$ and $H(\{p_0 \} \times [0,1]) = \{p_0\} \subset U$, there exist an open neighborhood $V$ of $p_0$ such that $H(V \times [0,1]) \subset U$. We have $p_0 \in U_{r_0}$ for some $r_0 \in [0,1)$. For each $p \in V$ the set $H(\{p\} \times [0,1])$ is a path connected subset of $U$ and contains $H(p,1) = p_0$, thus it must be contained in the path component $U_{r_0}$ of $p_0$ in $U$. But then also $p = H(p,0)  \in U_{r_0}$. Therefore $V \subset U_{r_0}$. This is a contradiction because any open $V$ must intersect infinitely many $U_r$.

What does it mean that $\{p_0\}$ is a deformation retract of $X$? It means nothing else than that the identity on $X$ is homotopic to the constant map with value $p_0$. But we already know that $X$ is contractible, hence all constant maps to $X$ are homotopic, and this proves that $\{p_0\}$ is a deformation retract of $X$ for **any** $p_0 \in X$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your analysis in the second to last paragraph. If $p_0 \notin [0,1] \times \{0\}$, and if we remove $Y$ from $X$, then clearly no paths can be established between $p_0$ and a point $p$ in another vertical segment. But isn't the question about such paths in the case that $Y$ not removed from $X$?

Comment: Also, in the second paragraph, I can see that the strong DR works. But am I correct to assume that we can just have DR here (instead of the strong version)? Would it make any difference if $p_0 \in [0,1] \times \{0\}$ moves around throughout the homotopy, as long as it returns to its original position when $t = 1$?

Comment: I edited my answer. For a DR the point $p_0$ may move around arbitrarily, and this gives you more freedom. Thus **any** $p_0 \in X$ is a DR of $X$.

Comment: I'm terribly to bother you again, but I read your answer and then re-read the question, but I don't see anything in the question that implies that the space we're considering is $X \setminus Y$. Obviously the argument would work if the space is the collection of disjointed vertical segments, as then the path induced by the homotopy $H$ would not be able to get from one segment to the other. But my understanding is that we don't have such assumption?

Comment: Two more questions: 1. I'd like more details on this part:"Since $U$ is an open neighborhood of $p_0$ and $H(\{p_0\} \times [0,1]) = \{p_0\} \subset U$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $p_0$ such that $H(V \times [0,1]) \subset U$". How can we be sure that for a $p \in V$, $H(p \times [0,1])$ doesn't intersect $Y$? 2. Just to be sure, I assume your notation $U_r$ denotes the vertical segment $r \times [0,1-r]$?

Comment: Of course we consider the whole space $X$ and a homotopy $H$ on this space. But $U$ is an open subset of $X$ containing $p_0$, and we have $H(\{p_0\} \times I) = \{p_0\}$, thus $\{p_0\} \times I \subset H^{-1}(U)$ and by compactness of $I$ we find an open neighborhood $V$ of $p_0$ such that $V  \times I \subset H^{-1}(U)$, i.e. $H(V  \times I) \subset U$. Thus by definition of $U$, $H(V  \times I)$ does not intersect $Y$. And that is all we need: An open subset $V$ of $X$ is deformed **within** $U$. And $U_r$ denotes the vertical segment $\{r\} \times (0,1-r]$ which does not contain $(r,0)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost thanks for the answers. I've been following the discussion, and there's just one details that's still unclear to me: the part where you deduce the existence of the set $V$ (i.e. the part with "by compactness of $I$" in the comment). Could you please elaborate on that? I've just started on the subject so my command of some of the tools is still not good enough.

Comment: @JoshNg This is the "tube lemma". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma.